# What are several different and alternative methods to backup the audio levels in linux?

Tags: audio, configuration, pulseaudio, volume, recording

The audio recording levels can be saved for Ubuntu / Debian users using a command from the package alsa-mixer,

```
alsactl --file ~/filename store
```

However I am looking for alternative ways to save and restore those levels, using perhaps aumix, pavucontrol or any other means to store the audio configuration in ways that can be restored later.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to keep in mind that there are several sets of controls:

1) The actual hardware controls in the Codec (audio chip)
2) The ALSA controls, that cover most (but often not all) hardware controls
3) The Pulseaudio controls, which are mostly software, though a few per-sink/per-source controls access the ALSA controls.

(1) depend on the hardware, but for Intel HDA, you can find them among other things in `/proc/asound/card*/codec\#*`. Not trivial to restore, though.

(2) is what you probably want. Besides `alsactl`, you can use `amixer` to access them (and `alsamixer` for a UI), e.g. `amixer -D hw:0 contents` for your first card (`cat /proc/asound/pcm` for a list). See `man amixer` on how to set them; you can use a shell script to extract the recording levels you want, and restore them later.

If you are running Pulseaudio, then without `-D`, you'll see the leves of the `pulse` pseudo-device that allows ALSA applications to access Pulseaudio. Also note that Pulseaudio my change settings on startup.

(3) can be done with `pacmd` or `pactl`; the output is not tool-friendly and requires a bit of parsing. See `pacmd help` and `pactl help` for details.

`aumix` is a legacy tool and probably won't work properly with ALSA or Pulseaudio.